# How do I write a simple makefile for a C project?

Tags: c, makefile

I've tried of reading articles of writing makefiles, I don't get it. I have a file structure like this.

```
- project
   - bin
      - main.exe
   - src
      - main.c
   - inc
      - ...
      - ...
```

I've tried different answers here, but those are complex for me for a beginner to understand. I need to have three commands in my makefile: `run` `compile` `clean`. I'm using GCC as a compiler.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried so far and any errors encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hellomake: hellomake.c hellofunc.c
 gcc -o hellomake hellomake.c hellofunc.c -I.
```

this is the optimal way to make an makeFile.
some cases you need to download even a plug in.
which software are you using?

Comment: I'm using singleton-based ArchWindows with extra GNU extensions.